# magento 2.3.2 bulk update price attribute is not working

Tags: magento

After upgrade magento 2.3.2 bulk update price attribute is not working it is showing on progress but if I update inventory qty then it update quickly

Comment: have you check log file? Is it showing error in it?

Comment: Not found any error

Comment: is it possible to share the console error?